# How to add/change ripple effect to a switch object

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-5.0-lollipop, ripple

Below is my custom switch, the red circle is the default ripple effect.
I found that setting a ripple drawable as the background of the switch
controls the color of the ripple:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/red_minus_category">
</ripple>
```

I want to change the circular ripple shape so it will be only inside the thumb part of the switch.

Thanks.

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_selector"
    android:showText="true"
    android:textOff="Some text"
    android:textOn="Other text"
    android:thumb="@drawable/new_deal_switch_thumb_selector"
    android:track="@drawable/rectangle_track"/>
```

[image]

Comment: You would need to put the `<ripple>` element inside your thumb drawable XML. If it's set as the background it will always show in the background.

Comment: @alanv setting android:thumb="@drawable/ripple_selector still draws the big circle, along with the correct ripple effect inside the switch button.

Comment: You will need to `@null` out the `android:background` attribute if you don't want the ripple background.